# How to display date with rggooglmap?

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I'm trying to display a `tt_address` birthday date with the *rggooglemap* extension.

So I placed the `###BIRTHDAY###` in the template but it display the date in UNIX. It give me something like `1409090400`.

Is there anything I can do to convert it with Typoscript ?

```
<!-- ###TEMPLATE_RECORDLIST_FIRST### -->
<div id="resultdiv">
<br/>
<table class="contenttable">
    <caption>###PB_STATISTIC### <br/>Page: ###PB_ACT###</caption>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Lieu d'installation</th>
        <th>Adresse</th>
        <th>Contact*</th>
        <th>Date d'autorisation</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <!-- ###CONTENT### -->

    <!-- ###SINGLE### -->
    <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="myclick(###UID###,###LNG###,###LAT###,'###TABLE###')">###NAME### </a></td>
        <td>###ADDRESS###<br/>###ZIP### ###CITY### </td>
        <td>###EMAIL###<br/>###PHONE###</td>
        <td>###BIRTHDAY###</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ###SINGLE### -->
    <!-- ###CONTENT### -->
    </td>
 </div>
 <!-- ###TEMPLATE_RECORDLIST_FIRST### -->
```

[image: Frontend result]

### Config

- TYPO3 4.7.10
- rggooglemap 3.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a timestamp to a human readable date just use the TypoScript parameter »strftime«.

I don't know how EXT:rggooglemap generates markers, but after a quick look into the code (function getMarker, line 1344) the following TypoScript should do the trick:

```
plugin.tx_rggooglemap_pi1 {
    ### view
    recordlist {
        ### field
        birthday {
            ### apply stdWrap
            ### convert timestamp to readable date
            strftime = %Y-%m-%d
        }
    }
}
```